# How to update a nxn matrix that contains shortest paths between nodes in n^2

Tags: algorithm

Suppose that A is an n by n matrix whose entry A[i, j] is the length of a
shortest path from node i to node j in an undirected and weighted graph G whose n nodes are
{1, 2, · · · , n}. Describe an O(n^2) algorithm that updates A, i.e., how to update A[i, j] for all
1 ≤ i, j ≤ n, when an additional edge (k, l) is inserted into G, where k and l are nodes of G

I am not sure how to go about this question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a moment to read [ask], as well as [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A shortest path from i to j in the new graph is either a shortest path in the original graph, or a new shortest path that uses the new edge. Such a new shortest path would be a shortest path from i to k, goes along the new edge to l, then a shortest path from l to j. Or it could go along the edge in the other direction: a shortest path from i to l, goes along the new edge to k, and then takes a shortest path from k to j.

Thus, if the new edge is from k to l with weight w, the new matrix A' looks like this:

```
A'[i, j] = min(A[i, j], A[i, k] + w + A[l, j], A[i, l] + w + A[k, j])
```

All that remains is to note that you don't need special cases to handle when i or j is equal to k or l, and you can do the above operations in-place in A, in any order.